# API for Contributing to Google Translate

Tags: api, google-translate, community-translations

I want to be able to contribute to Google Translate on my native language (Sinhala).

Although there is an online portal (http://translate.google.com/community/) where we can contribute to the translator by translating new phrases or validating existing translations, I would like to create my own, lightweight portal (maybe an Android app) for the contribution service. However, I was unable to find any public API for the translate contribution platform, despite a thorough Google search and a full search through the Google Translator Toolkit API forum (https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!categories/translator-toolkit-api) (which seems to have been closed down since the end of 2012).

Currently my best hope is to mimic the request-response sequence followed by the online portal itself. For example, the following request is used by the online portal to fetch a question list for manual translation:

`GET http://translate.google.com/community/question_list?sl=en&tl=si&client=t`

However, it requires that all the related cookies are properly initialized and passed with the request, which would probably not be easy to mimic in a non-browser environment (such as an Android app). Hence I believe there's a better approach (maybe a yet undocumented API?) somewhere out there.

Does anyone know of any API for accessing this translation contribution feature?

Thanks in advance.

**Please note:** I am NOT looking for a way to improve Google Translate itself, but for contributing to the actual translation content as described under "How can I help?" in the Google Translate Community FAQ (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dwS4CZzgZwmvoB9pAx4A6Yytmv7itk_XE968RMiqpMY/pub#h.e1ahmpftpdum).

**P.S.** I was initially planning to post this question on the Web Apps Stack Exchange, but after reading [this](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/740/are-api-questions-on-topic-or-off-topic) post I decided to first try it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the engineers behind Translate Community and I'm really excited that you want to see it on more platforms.  We're currently under active development of the site and making it more accessible on mobile platforms without having to create dedicated native apps.

For the time being, we don't anticipate releasing a public API as the platform is under active development.  Until we do release a public API, please don't use any http commands you find to create a separate app.  Instead, just let us know how we can make the app a better experience for you and we'll work on making it better.

Thanks!

Comment: That's great, thanks! By the way, is there some kind of developer community (maybe a forum) where I can check this kind of details (and contribute, if possible)? The Translate Toolkit API forum (https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!categories/translator-toolkit-api) seems to be dead for a long time, and the only method of 'communication' I could find was the feedback form available on Translate Community pages.

Comment: For right now, our G+ page (https://plus.sandbox.google.com/+GoogleTranslate) is the best way to keep up to date with Community and communicate with us.  We're still working on better tools for discussions for Community users.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. BTW let's hope something better and more 'official' would come up soon.